# Best algorithm for comparing 2 collections of objects and determine which objects have been edited and which are new

Tags: c#, performance, collections, change-tracking

If you have a collection of objects (Col A), with possible duplicates, and you would like to know, based on data structured the same way already present in the database, which objects in this collection have been edited and which are completely new, what algorithms would you apply in what order for best results?

I have tried the following steps with very slow results:

1. Transform to hashset and back to collection A to remove duplicates
2. Sort the collection based on primary key properties
3. Retrieve objects (collection B) present in DB based of data in first object (>=) and last object (<=) of collection A.
4. Iterate through collection A to find object in collection B

   - If not present put in collection NewObjects
   - If present compare all properties 1 by 1 to see if object is dirty and subsequently put in collection EditedObjects

Alas, there is too much messy code to show anything useful.

I don't believe my approach is optimal and would like to know if there are smarter alternatives

Comment: well you could certainly have an enum for old, dirty and new... where dirty is set if you change it, new is set if you make it... and then work from there

Comment: These kinds of comparisons are usually messy. You can't do much about that.